# Model moves around with camera, instead of staying still

Tags: c#, 3d, camera, xna, monogame

I am creating a Monogame first person shooter game, at least learning to do such and I have hit an issue that I cant seem to figure out. I have a first person camera with mouse + keyboard input, and a floor that I can move around over, so essentially a basic "3d world".

Now I wanted to draw a 3D model of a ball at the locations 0, 10, 0 (or anywhere really) but when I move around my camera, the ball stays in place, center of my camera and moves with me.

Does anyone know the issues? I have a camera class and trying to draw my model within the game class. I think it is something to do with me using multiple matrix's?

Camera class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Game7
{
    class Camera : GameComponent
    {
        private Vector3 cameraPosition;
        private Vector3 cameraRotation;
        private float cameraSpeed;
        private Vector3 cameraLookAt;

        private Vector3 mouseRotationBuffer;
        private MouseState currentMouseState;
        private MouseState previousMouseState;



        // Properties

        public Vector3 Position
        {
            get { return cameraPosition; }
            set
            {
                cameraPosition = value;
                UpdateLookAt();
            }
        }

        public Vector3 Rotation
        {
            get { return cameraRotation; }
            set
            {
                cameraRotation = value;
                UpdateLookAt();
            }
        }

        public Matrix Projection
        {
            get;
            protected set;
        }

        public Matrix View
        {
            get
            {
                return Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraLookAt, Vector3.Up);
            }
        }

        //Constructor 
        public Camera(Game game, Vector3 position, Vector3 rotation, float speed)
            : base(game)
        {
            cameraSpeed = speed;

            // projection matrix
            Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                MathHelper.PiOver4, 
                Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio,
                0.05f, 
                1000.0f);

            // set camera positiona nd rotation
            MoveTo(position, rotation);

            previousMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        }

        // set Camera's position and rotation
        private void MoveTo(Vector3 pos, Vector3 rot)
        {
            Position = pos;
            Rotation = rot;
        }

        //update the look at vector
        private void UpdateLookAt()
        {
            // build rotation matrix
            Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(cameraRotation.X) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(cameraRotation.Y);
            // Look at ofset, change of look at
            Vector3 lookAtOffset = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.UnitZ, rotationMatrix);
            // update our cameras look at vector
            cameraLookAt = cameraPosition + lookAtOffset;
        }

        // Simulated movement
        private Vector3 PreviewMove(Vector3 amount)
        {
            // Create rotate matrix
            Matrix rotate = Matrix.CreateRotationY(cameraRotation.Y);
            // Create a movement vector
            Vector3 movement = new Vector3(amount.X, amount.Y, amount.Z);
            movement = Vector3.Transform(movement, rotate);

            return cameraPosition + movement; 

        }

        // Actually move the camera
        private void Move(Vector3 scale)
        {
            MoveTo(PreviewMove(scale), Rotation);
        }

        // updat method
        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // smooth mouse?
            float dt = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

            KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();

            // input

            Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.Zero;

            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                moveVector.Z = 1;
            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                moveVector.Z = -1;
            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                moveVector.X = 1;
            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                moveVector.X = -1;

            if (moveVector != Vector3.Zero)
            {
                //normalize it
                //so that we dont move faster diagonally
                moveVector.Normalize();
                // now smooth and speed
                moveVector *= dt * cameraSpeed;
                // move camera
                Move(moveVector);
            }

            // Handle mouse input

            float deltaX;
            float deltaY;

            if(currentMouseState != previousMouseState)
            {
                //Cache mouse location
                deltaX = currentMouseState.X - (Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2);
                deltaY = currentMouseState.Y - (Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);

                // smooth mouse ? rotation
                mouseRotationBuffer.X -= 0.01f * deltaX * dt;
                mouseRotationBuffer.Y -= 0.01f * deltaY * dt;

                if (mouseRotationBuffer.Y < MathHelper.ToRadians(-75.0f))
                    mouseRotationBuffer.Y = mouseRotationBuffer.Y - (mouseRotationBuffer.Y - MathHelper.ToRadians(-75.0f));
                if (mouseRotationBuffer.Y > MathHelper.ToRadians(75.0f))
                    mouseRotationBuffer.Y = mouseRotationBuffer.Y - (mouseRotationBuffer.Y - MathHelper.ToRadians(75.0f));

                Rotation = new Vector3(-MathHelper.Clamp(mouseRotationBuffer.Y, MathHelper.ToRadians(-75.0f), MathHelper.ToRadians(75.0f)), MathHelper.WrapAngle(mouseRotationBuffer.X), 0);

                deltaX = 0;
                deltaY = 0;

            }

            // Alt + F4 to close now.
            Mouse.SetPosition(Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);

            previousMouseState = currentMouseState;

                base.Update(gameTime);
        }


    }
}
```

And the game class:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Game7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game.
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Camera camera;
        Floor floor;
        BasicEffect effect;

        Model ball;

        private Matrix world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 10, 0));
        private Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 10), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.UnitY);
        private Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45), 800f / 480f, 0.1f, 100f);

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            camera = new Camera(this, new Vector3(10f, 1f, 5f), Vector3.Zero, 5f);
            Components.Add(camera);
            floor = new Floor(GraphicsDevice, 40, 40);
            effect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);



            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            ball = Content.Load<Model>("Ball DAE");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// game-specific content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            floor.Draw(camera, effect);
            DrawModel(ball, world, view, projection);
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        private void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
        {
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    //effect.World = world;
                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = projection;
                }

                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Oh, and if I uncomment the effect.world = world, then the ball doesn't draw at all.

Answer (score 0):

ouTo draw a model, the effect needs a world, view, and projection matrices. Your code indicates you don't have a clear grasp on what goes where.

The world is a matrix that represents the model's rotation & position relative to the world. This matrix changes as the model moves or rotates.

The view is a matrix that represents the camera's rotation and position relative to the world (more accurately, the world's position/rotation relative to the camera). This matrix is usually owned by the camera class and the same view matrix is used to draw all objects.

The projection matrix represents how the world appears. Kinda like a lens on a camera. This matrix is also usually owned by the camera class and the same projection matrix is used to draw all objects.

Your game class has a private world, view, and projection matrices that you use to draw the model. You also have a view and projection matrix created in the camera class that draws the floor. You have to use the same view & projection for the floor and the ball. So probably you should use the camera's view & projection to draw the ball like you are with the floor.

```
effect.View = camera.View;
effect.Projection = camera.Projection;
```

Comment: That is somewhat how I thought it should be, sadly it still hasn't fixed the issue. The ball now doesn't draw at all.

Comment: It appears that your world matrix that you have commented out would place the ball 10 units above the camera's lookAt point. It may just be out of view. Change the world matrix to Matrix.Identity and see if that helps. Also, your camera class is hard to follow and looks overly complex and possibly error prone. Here is a simplified camera class that offers the kind of movement yours does. http://pastebin.com/sKqhtyqJ

Comment: Oh my, that is embarrassing, haha there it is, hovering way above me in the sky. Didnt think to look all the way up for it. Thank you for your time and help!